# Find sum of elements in the array

Tags: c, arrays

I have this program which worked find in my college lab, but when I run it at my home it gives different result

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        const int size=100;
        int n, sum=0;
        int* A = (int*)malloc( sizeof(int)*size );
        for (n=size-1; n>0; n--)
                A[n] = n;

        for (n=0;n<size; n++)
                sum += A[n];

        printf ("sum=%d\n", sum);
        return 0;

}
```

I'm expecting `4950` as result but I keep getting different result like `112133223`. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not assigning value to `A[0]`. As a result of this `A[0]` will have garbage value which is getting added to `sum`.

Change

```
for (n=size-1; n>0; n--)
               ^^^
```

to

```
for (n=size-1; n>=0; n--)
               ^^^^
```

Also you need to free the dynamically allocated memory by doing:

```
free(A);
```

before you return.

Answer (score 2):

You never assign a value to A[0] - the first loop ends to quickly. However you do include this unassigned value in the summation.

Answer (score 1):

`A[0]` is undefined:

`for (n=size-1; n>0; n--)`

should be

`for (n=size-1; n>=0; n--)`

Answer (score 1):

Just because you didn't put any value in first element, you had garbage there. thus, some random number in sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> //for malloc
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        const int size=100;
        int n, sum=0;
        int* A = (int*)malloc( sizeof(int)*size );
        for (n=size-1; n>=0; n--) //you forgot '='
                A[n] = n;

        for (n=0;n<size; n++)
                sum += A[n];

        printf ("sum=%d\n", sum);
        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked fine for me. I executed it using GCC. this is the program i ran:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int size=100;
    int n, sum=0;
    int* A = (int*)malloc( sizeof(int)*size );
    for (n=size-1; n>0; n--)
            A[n] = n;

    for (n=0;n<size; n++)
            sum += A[n];

    printf ("sum=%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```